# iMac logging out whenever seemingly stressful programs are launched

Tags: macos, imac, mojave, crash

Recently my mac has been mysteriously logging itself out whenever I attempt to launch any resource-intensive programs, such as games (roblox) and 3D applications. I have looked at many solutions to similar problems online, such as resetting PRAM and NVRAM, and have even gone so far as to reinstall MacOS. Yet the problem persists. 
When I open said applications, they work for about 2-3 minutes and then suddenly freeze before the screen goes black and a small loading icon appears and then it takes me to the login screen.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Whenever it crashes, files such as this pop up in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticsReports

```
Kernel_2019-10-29-124911_Username-iMac-7.gpuRestart
```

And the content:

[image]

That's what I get when it crashes with blender, but I'm also getting some WindowServer logs too.
[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/373707/edit) your question to include your model of iMac? I have some suspicions as to what's going on, but knowing your hardware details will help.

Comment: A guess would be OpenGL issues - possibly memory. If you are running 2 apps that use OpenGL, they don't share very well. Photoshop etc is also bad for this if running alongside games. If you can check with the game maker for how to reduce OpenGL memory [or check that's in fact what the game uses] & report back.

Comment: Have you checked if heat could be an issue?

Comment: The fan doesn't appear to be ramping up, and the hardware check says it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for your issue is most likely related to the graphics processing unit (GPU) of your iMac. This is what's commonly referred to as a graphics card.

Some games and applications will place the GPU under a much heavier load compared to others.

For example, using a word processor will not tax the GPU much at all, but using applications such as Photoshop, Maya, Render, Final Cut Pro, Motion, etc will place a much heavier burden on the GPU. I'm not familiar with Roblox, but it's likely that it's also taxing the GPU heavily.

Normally this would not be a problem, but if your Mac has a GPU that has developed a problem, it'll be enough to effectively cause it to crash in such a way that your Mac has to reboot. In this scenario it's a hardware fault that may mean repairing or replacing the GPU.

Some Mac models were more prone than others to these types of problems. For example, the 27" iMac model from mid-2011 was the subject of a graphics card replacement program for exactly this type of issue.

However, it doesn't necessarily have to be a hardware fault. Software can often cause problems. For example, it could be a conflict between software, drivers, etc or a lack of graphics memory (especially if running multiple apps simultaneously). You could try troubleshooting this further by only running one application and seeing what happens. Perhaps testing in Safe Mode may be an option as well.

---

**Remove any CUDA and NVIDIA drivers**

Since you're running macOS Mojave (or above), you should be aware that any CUDA and NVIDIA drivers you have installed aren't supported.

To remove these:

1. Launch Terminal (found within your Utilities folder)
2. Copy and paste the following commands, one by one, into Terminal followed by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on your keyboard. Each time you do this you'll also have to enter your Admin password.

   - `sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/CUDA.kext`
   - `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/CUDA.framework`
   - `sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.nvidia.CUDASoftwareUpdate.plist`
   - `sudo rm -rf /System/Library/StartupItems/CUDA`
   - `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda`
3. Go to Apple > System Preferences
4. Right-click on the CUDA preference pane
5. Select the *Remove "CUDA" preference pane* option

**OPTIONAL:** If you also have NVIDIA Web Drivers installed (that's a 'yes' if you have the NVIDIA icon in the menu bar), then follow these additional steps:

6. Still in System Preferences, click the NVIDIA Driver Manager preference pane
7. Select the Graphics Drivers tab
8. Click on the padlock and type your password
9. Click the <kbd>Open Uninstaller</kbd> button
10. Click Uninstall
11. Complete the Uninstall process and restart your iMac

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out! If it's any help now, I'm using a 27-inch, Late 2013 iMac with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M. I'll update the CUDA drivers (something I haven't done in a while).
I did try running just one application and it still causes this problem.

Comment: Well, it hasn't solved the problem. I install Catalina and installed the latest CUDA updates but it's still doing it. One thing I've also noticed is that the speed has also deteriorated too. It happened pretty suddenly last Saturday afternoon and since then has been really slow.

Comment: Ah rip, it's just done it again without any applications open aside from finder.
I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: I'm currently in safe mode and some funky stuff is happening. Typing this message is quite weird because I can only see half of the text, the top half is cut off, the google 'New tab' page is doing some funny things too, and Blender (My 3D application) and all that happens is a message that pops up saying that blender has quit unexpectedly.

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculous amount of updates, but I did the apple hardware check and that didn't reveal anything, which leads me to hope that it's just a solvable software problem.

Comment: I would try uninstalling the NVidia 3rd party drivers. None are qualified for anything later than High Sierra. Go back to just the Apple drivers & see if anything changes.

Comment: Nope, it still happens. I deleted all the CUDA stuff, restarted, and it's still messing itself up.

Comment: 'deleted' or actually uninstalled?

Comment: Well I couldn't find any uninstaller, so I went and removed the cuda files from the system.

Comment: The only issue that comes to mind quickly re your model was the [iMac Graphics Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1808), although there may be others. Can you clarify what browser you're using? Google Chrome usually has hardware acceleration enabled by default and this is known to cause issues on many systems. As far as further diagnosis, what happens if you just use your iMac without any graphics intensive software running? Also, at the time this behaviour started, did anything else change (e.g. added new hardware or software, installed software updates, etc)?

Comment: As per @Tetsujin - I would remove any of the 3rd party NVDIA drivers. I've updated my answer to explain how.

Comment: I'm using Chrome yes, I did try disabling hardware acceleration but it didn't make any difference. It does appear to be working better now, though it's a little stop-and-start, just lagging a lot.
It seems to be working fine, and youtube vids were and are absolutely fine.
When it changed I hadn't installed or changed anything to my knowledge.

Comment: Nope, it's back to crashing again.

Comment: But none-graphics intensive stuff works fine. Even watching youtube is good. Just these programs. I attempted to reinstall them but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: So, the GPU has been Resetting every now and again when under strain, but it doesn't always shut down, only after it's reset a few times. I've also edit my original question to include some crash reports. @Tetsujin

Comment: Blender is Open GL. idk what Skylight is.

Comment: What's skylight? @Tetsujin

Comment: It's what crashed on your 2nd log

Comment: Anything I can do??

Comment: Well, your logs confirm what I said in my answer - namely that it's related to your GPU in some way. As for skylight, that's just the CoreGraphicsServices framework, so not the cause of your issue. If it was me, I would try running your iMac from a total fresh installation, perhaps from an external drive, and perhaps from an older version of macOS (perhaps High Sierra) and then test without any of your graphics intensive apps installed. Assuming all is good, I would then install **one** app, such as Blender, and use that to see if you run into problems. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you so much for you help, I'll let you know how it goes.